# NPAPI tutorial, Gecko SDK

Tags: mozilla, npapi, geckosdk

Hi im following [this simple tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Compiling_The_npruntime_Sample_Plugin_in_Visual_Studio) on mozilla developers site.

im getting some errors in BUILD phase and one thing that i couldn't follow in tutorial was under Version Issues

> 1. If you are using Gecko SDK v1.9 and higher, you'll probably need to add folders \plugin, \nspr, and \java as included directories

from the C:\xulrunner-sdk\include Folder i found "nspr" folder, but there is no folder named "plugin" or "java".
i found a folder named C:\xulrunner-sdk\include\mozilla\plugin**s**. But no name similar to Java..
Anyone knows where they are, i downloaded Gecko SDK from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko_SDK), that\s the link from tutorial.
If anyone has more experience with this and can help, then thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly that article is outdated; you don't need the Gecko SDK (i updated the article, but only quickly went over the obvious issues and didn't check the referenced sample etc.).

All you need to build NPAPI plugins are the headers in the **[NPAPI SDK](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/)**.
[This plugin](https://github.com/bsmedberg/blue-fishmonger-testplugin) should have a properly configured VS solution, although you'll probably have to adopt the include path to your local copy of the NPAPI SDK.